# appropriateness of the term 'social-navigation' in this context

Tags: word-choice

This is from [a *TIME* article](https://time.com/6158182/vitalik-buterin-ethereum-profile/).

> With the founders splintered, Buterin emerged as Ethereum’s
> philosophical leader. He had a seat on the EF board and the clout to
> shape industry trends and move markets with his public pronouncements.
> He even became known as “V God” in China. But he didn’t exactly step
> into the power vacuum. “He’s not good at bossing people around,” says
> Aya Miyaguchi, the executive director of the EF. “From a
> **social-navigation** perspective, he was immature. He’s probably still
> conflict-averse,” says Danny Ryan, a lead researcher at the EF.
> Buterin calls his struggle to inhabit the role of an organizational
> leader “my curse for the first few years at Ethereum.”

From what I read on the internet, the difinition of 'social-navigation' is [as follows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_navigation#:%7E:text=Social%20navigation%20is%20a%20form,or%20a%20group%20of%20others%22.):

> Social navigation is a form of social computing introduced by Paul
> Dourish and Matthew Chalmers in 1994, who defined it as when "movement
> from one item to another is provoked as an artifact of the activity of
> another or a group of others".

So it seems to me the term 'social navigation' has nothing to do with his being poor at bossing people around or conflict-averse.

I think 'social skill perspective' is more appropriate than 'social-navigation perspective'.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea.

I assume that Danny Ryan was responding to a spoken interview question and was not choosing his words as effectively as possible. The term **social navigation** as Wikipedia defines it does not fit the context.

But please do not think that **From a social-skill perspective** is the best revision. It's very bureaucratic—the sort of thing a manager says in the kind of meeting that everyone hates to attend. There is no need to mention a **perspective** at all. The following is more natural and direct: **He was socially immature.**

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.